# $a^*$ and $a^{**}$ in wikipedia's proof of IVT

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I am following the proof of the IVT on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), and have one point of confusion. In the proof they say

> By the properties of the supremum, there exists some $a^* \in (c-\delta, c]$ that is contained in $S$, and so
> $$f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon \leq u + \epsilon$$
> Picking $a^{**} \in (c, c+\delta)$, we know that $a^{**} \not \in S$ because $c$ is the supremum of $S$. This means that
> $$f(c) > f(a^{**}) - \epsilon > u -\epsilon$$

What bothers me is how this proof is splitting the half intervals. How are we sure that for example $a^*$ exists? If this comes from continuity, how do we not know that such an $a^*$ only  exists in the other half of the interval? Likewise for $a^{**}$.

Comment: $c =\sup\{$ all $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x) \le u\}$.  That mean no number less than $c$ can be an upper bound of $\{$ all $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x) \le u\}$.  So $c-\delta$ can not be an upper bound of $\{$ all $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x) \le u\}$.  So there is a $a^* > c-\delta$ so that $a^* \in \{$ all $x\in [a,b]$ so that $f(x) \le u\}$.  And thus $f(a^*)\le u$.

Comment: @fleablood But how can you assure that $f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon$?

Comment: And *that* is from continuity.  If $c-\delta < a^*\le c$ then $|c-a^*| < \delta$ and so $|f(c) - f(a^*)| < \epsilon$ so $-\epsilon < f(a^*) - f(c) < \epsilon$ so $f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon < 2\epsilon$.

Comment: @fleablood Ah I see, so essentially it follows from the definition of continuity of which we only consider the right handside of the inequality? I guess it did not occur to me that we can only consider half of the inequality. Is that justified in general without having to check if the other side of the inequality is satisfied?

Comment: Well as you have $c = \sup\{x|f(x)\le u\}$ then for any $x > c$ we have $x \not \in \{x|f(x)\le u\}$ and $f(x) > u$ so there is no point in considering $(c, c+\delta)$.   Alternativel, you could have used and $\inf \{x|f(x)\ge u\}$ and do the $[c, c+\delta)$ interval.

Comment: @fleablood What still is not entirely clicking his how splitting the interval still leads to the inequality $f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon$. I understand why we do it but not how.

Comment: $|x-c|<\delta \iff c-\delta<x<c+\delta\iff x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$. By continuity, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$ so that $x\in(c-\delta]\subset(c-\delta,c+\delta)\implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon\implies f(c)< f(x)+\epsilon$. And we don't care about $x\in(c,c+\delta)$ because $x\in(c,c+\delta)\implies f(x)>u$.... and By *supremum* there exists an $a^*\in(c-\delta, c]$ so that $f(a^*) \le u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Continuity means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that for all $|x-c|< \delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$.

So if $c-\delta < x \le c$ then $|x-c| < \delta$ and $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ so $f(c) < f(x) + \epsilon$.

> And $c =\sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$ means that $c$ is an upper bound of  $\sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$ and that any number less than $c$ will *not* be an upper bound of $\sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$.

$c-\delta < c$ so $c-\delta$ is *not* an upper bound of $\sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$.  And $c$ *is* an upper bound of $\sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$.  That means there must exist a $a^*$ so that $c-\delta < a^* \le c$ where $a^* \in \sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$.

So $a^* \in (c-\delta, c]$.  And we have $a^* \in \sup \{y| f(y) \le u\}$ so $f(a^*) \le u$.

So that means $f(a^*) + \epsilon \le u + \epsilon$.

And so we have

1. $c-\delta < a^* \le c$
2. For all $x\in(c-\delta, c]$ that $f(c) < f(x) +\epsilon$ so $f(c) < f(a^*) +\epsilon$.
3. $f(a^*) +\epsilon \le u+ \epsilon$

The $f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon \le u + \epsilon$.

So for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$f(x) \le u + \epsilon$.

Comment: This has helped me pinpoint my confusion, which is the first part of your answer. Since continuity implies for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-c| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$, how does this imply $x \in (c-\delta, c] \Rightarrow f(c) < f(x) + \epsilon$? How are we sure that points to the left of $c$ will map to points $x$ such that $f(c) < f(x) + \epsilon$?

Comment: $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon \implies -\epsilon<f(c)-f(x)<\epsilon\implies f(x)-\epsilon < f(c)<f(x)+\epsilon\implies f(c)<f(x)+\epsilon$.

Comment: So By continuity $c-\delta<x\le c\implies c-\delta<x<c+\delta\implies f(x)-\epsilon < f(c)<f(x)+\epsilon\implies f(c)<f(x)+\epsilon$. And by Supremum, there exists an $a^*: c-\delta< a^*\le c$ so that $a^*\in\{x|f(x)\le u\}\implies f(a^*)\le u$.  So.... we have $c-\delta <a^*\le c$ so $f(c)< f(a^*)+\epsilon\le u + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$. That can only happen if $f(c)\le u$.  [Now we need an argument that $f(c)\not< u$ but that's clear by continuity....]

Answer (score 3):

We have $S=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\le u\}$ and $c=\sup(S)$. This means two things:

1. Since $c$ is an upper bound for $S$, any number larger than $c$ is not in $S$. That is, for any $x$ in the domain with $c<x$, we have $f(x)>u$.
2. Since $c$ is the *least* upper bound for $S$, any number smaller than $c$ is *not* an upper bound for $S$. In other words, if $x<c$, then since $x$ is not an upper bound there must be some element $a^*\in S$ which is larger than $x$. But $c$ is still an upper bound for $S$, so $x<a^*<c$.

Comment: Regarding 2: The double negatives always confuse me. I find it useful to think "if there were no such element $a^*$ between $x$ and $c$, then $x$ would be a better bound."

Comment: @So then does $f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon$ then follow from continuity? Since $a^* \in (c-\delta, c] \subset (c-\delta, c+\delta)$ and hence $f(a^*) - \epsilon < f(c) < f(a^*) + \epsilon$ and we only consider the right handside of the inequality?